# "Recived error message from Relay: self-connect not allowed." issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After I put the join code and connect to host this error pops out ""Recived error message from Relay: self-connect not allowed.". Have no idea how to fix it.

```
public async void CreateLobby()
    {
       Allocation a = await RelayService.Instance.CreateAllocationAsync(5);
       joinCode.text = await RelayService.Instance.GetJoinCodeAsync(a.AllocationId);

       transport.SetHostRelayData(a.RelayServer.IpV4, (ushort)a.RelayServer.Port,      a.AllocationIdBytes, a.Key, a.ConnectionData);

       NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();
    }
    public async void JoinGame()
    {
        JoinAllocation a = await RelayService.Instance.JoinAllocationAsync(inputCode.text);
        transport.SetClientRelayData(a.RelayServer.IpV4, (ushort)a.RelayServer.Port, a.AllocationIdBytes, a.Key, a.ConnectionData, a.ConnectionData);

        NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();

    }
```

Ofcourse i want the client to conect to the host.

Comment: Are you running both instances on the same PC?

Comment: Yes but running it on different device (even on different network) doesnt solve the issue. At least for me it doesnt.

Comment: Also from what I've seen on videos it should also work on the same PC so I dont get it, why it throws this error.